# AttributeError: 'InteractionResponse' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Tags: pycord

How to make the issuance of a role on the button? I can't manage...

Google translator

```
@client.slash_command() # Create a slash command
async def button(ctx):
    button = Button(label="Verif", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)

    async def button_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.add_roles(1075847753495756860)

    button.callback = button_callback
    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="<:fileandfolder:1066266358171586611> | **Verif**", description="> Test")
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/lvSiQm8.png")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed, view=view) # Send a message with our View class that contains the button
```

help to make the issuance of a role on the button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a role to the user who pressed the button then we need to use the [`user`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.user) paramater on [`interaction`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Interaction) to do so. You can see more about button callbacks [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.Button.callback).

```py
async def button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = interaction.user
    try:
        role = interaction.guild.get_role(1075847753495756860)
        await user.add_roles(role)
    except (discord.Forbidden, discord.HTTPException):
        # failed to get the role
        await interaction.respond("Something went wrong adding the role", ephemeral=True)
        return

    await interaction.respond("Given you the role", ephemeral=True)
```

Here, we use `interaction.user` to get the user that pressed the button. Within a guild context, this should be a [`discord.Member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Member) that has the [`add_roles`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Member.add_roles) method. We also use the [`interaction.guild`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.guild) property to get the [`discord.Guild`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#guild) object and use the [`get_role`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Guild.get_role) method to get the Role object for the given role. We can then use that to add that role to the member.

I've also added some basic responses so the user doesn't get a "This interaction has failed" message and some try/except in case we can't add the role for whatever reason.